# Installing imagick library extension on xampp Windows?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I have to convert pdf to image format (jpg or png) for a thesis project and was planning to install the imagick library on xampp which proved to be tricky. By the way, the php version that I currently have is **PHP 7.4.3**.

I based the steps in installing imagick through this link: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/349/how-to-install-and-enable-the-imagick-extension-in-xampp-for-windows
[image: Information on PHP]

1. Installed imageMagick (ImageMagick-7.0.10-0-Q16-x64-dll.exe
   )on my Windows 10 pc (upon checking with the `magick -version` and was able to display the imageMagick version installed on the pc.)
2. Added php_imagick.dll to xampp/php/ext which I got from PHP PECL website.
    3.4.4  stable  2019-05-02  imagick-3.4.4.tgz (247.5kB)  DLL
3. Enabled the extension on php.ini file through extension=imagick
4. Added the binaries which I got from PECL DEPS (IMO and CORE .dlls).
   11/23/2017  3:58 PM     47633113 ImageMagick-7.0.7-11-vc15-x64.zip

Upon running phpinfo() it displayed the following items:

[image: Imagick Library Module Specifications]

5. I decided to test the library using the code
     `<?php
   $image = new Imagick();
   $image->newImage(1, 1, new ImagickPixel('#ffffff'));
   $image->setImageFormat('png');
   $pngData = $image->getImagesBlob();
   echo strpos($pngData, "\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n") === 0 ? 'Ok' : 'Failed';  ?>`
   but web page is **blank**.
6. I tried adding the xampp/apache/bin to PATH in Windows to fix the problem but the problem is still there. In addition, this what php intelephense (extension in vscode) produced:
   [image]

Is there anyone out there who can give any advice on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use Imagemagick directly? You can then create batch files with standard settings you can drop your file into. You need to install Ghostscript before Imagemagick and Imagemagick will link to it auotmatically

As long as you allowed it to set the environmental variables during install this should work as a batch file:

```
magick -density 400 %1 "%~n1.png"
```

You can add whatever you want to the line.

You could also run from the command line with:

```
 magick -density 400 "Path\to\input.pdf" "Path\to\th_%~n1.png"
```

Edit to answer the comment:

I have two websites using Imagemagick directly in php with exec(). I do not use Imagik as I find Imagemagick simpler and it has more options. Imagick is supposed to be safer and a bit quicker.
On a server you would use something like this:

> exec("magick -density 400 \"Path\to\input.pdf\" \"Path\to\output.png\"
>   ");

Not sure about link posting here but check out my profile

Comment: Will your method work if I was planning to make a pdf to image converter function for a webpage? I am not familiar with creating batch files nor ghostscript as of the moment.

Comment: I tried running the IM command using the sample from your site and it works. Thanks.